# Error when initialize Koala Gem - undefined method `synchronize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, koala, koala-gem

I'm using koala version 2.3.0 + omniauth-facebook 3.0.0

I'm trying to do this:

**user_facebook_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_facebook_token)
user_facebook_api.get_object("me")**

When I try this in the console, it returns my profile correctly.

But on the server, it returns this exception

**NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `synchronize' for nil:NilClass**

---

Does anyone know what could be wrong

Full Trace of Server bellow

Already, thanks

---

Full Trace of Server

/home/nonato/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/singleton.rb:139:in `instance'
multi_json (1.11.2) lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:21:in`load'
multi_json (1.11.2) lib/multi_json.rb:119:in `load'
koala (2.3.0) lib/koala/api.rb:89:in`api'
koala (2.3.0) lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:527:in `graph_call'
koala (2.3.0) lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:116:in`get_connection'
app/controllers/facebook_integrations_controller.rb:86:in `load_facebook_pages'

Comment: What does the statement `Mutex.ancestors` return on both your development and production environments?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your attention, Mutext.ancestors return this (on production and development):

`[Mutex, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Socket::Constants, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: this problem seems to be intermittent. Sometimes gives this error, at other times works as it should work.